# Using Chrome's heap snapshot analyzer, how do I interpret dead-ends in the retainers view

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I have a single-page app that is leaking fairly substantially.  I am trying to track down the memory leaks using Chrome's built-in memory profiling tools.  The heap snapshot has been giving me a lot of success in tracking down quite a few problematic code blocks, but I have now reached a bit of a dead-end.

I have taken a heap snapshot and isolated a variable that has clearly leaked.  I then open it up the retainers view so that I can see why the object has not been garbage collected.  What I am now seeing in the retainers view (see below) is confusing me.  It keeps reaching a dead-end even though it claims that the given node in the graph still has a distance of 11.  I'm not sure why it won't let me dig into the object when it says that there is still depth there.  I was expecting that I would be able to expand all the way to a global variable on the window object.

[image]